# add labels next to each other on specific width

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I would like to create a loop that takes a JSON array and for each arrayValue in the json input create a new text label, that autosizes to the size of the text, and places itself in a view, where each subsequent label is placed adjacent to the previous, until it cannot fit in the screen in 
which case it creates a new row beneath.

label 1 | label 2 | label 3 | label 4

label 5| label 6| label 7|

how do you programmatically create labels ?

i try to create it manually but it take so time :(

Comment: You need a UICollectionView.

Comment: lol , i didn't think about that , it would be good idea ^^" ty